# No me deja borrar datos de una tabla

Tags: mysql

Intento eliminar un alumno y me da este error, y no sé por qué.

```
    DELETE FROM `test`.`alumno` WHERE (`id` = '45');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: El error es muy claro: `Incorrect Integer value` quiere decir que la columna es entero y tú le estás proporcionando una cadena. Solo tienes que eliminar las comillas simples y dejar el número. `WHERE \`id\` = 45`

Comment: ¿De casualidad hay triggers y/o constraints involucrados?

Comment: @Triby no es por las comillas, en MySQL ocurren [conversiones automáticas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html), [aquí](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rnT8YkpmDPZ7ppsocGAk2D/0) un ejemplo.

Comment: @Sal, ciertamente en MySQL está configurado así por defecto, pero no en MariaDB donde hay que desactivar el modo estricto ([referencia](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/incorrect-integer-value/)) o activar otra directiva que no recuerdo ahora.

Answer (score 0):

Error de sintaxis, estás haciendo referencia a un tipo de dato string cuando en la db es un entero. Prueba lo siguiente

```
DELETE FROM `test`.`alumno` WHERE (`id` = 45);
```